# Bash backup script. Need help finding a file and reading it

Tags: linux, bash, backup

Hi my fist time trying to write a bash script so im kinda bad at it.

I need help with locating a file in a home dir( this file contains a list of files i want to backup). After this i want to loop all lines in the file and make copies of the files.

this is what i have tryed but it dont seem to work:

```
find /home$n -name .file_with_backup_register | while read line ;
do cp "$line" /var/backup/temp;
done
```

when im trying to make my tar backup in the script with `tar-czvf $(date +%m_%d_%Y)` il get:

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive.
```

So im guessing its the find /home$n... line that dosent work

Comment: Show how you're putting `tar` into the backup script. The problem is probably with how you're specifying the files to put in the archive.

Comment: tar-czvf $(date +%m_%d_%Y) im standing in /var/backup/temp and want to make a tar of the complete dir with the name month,day,year

Comment: Your `while read` loop doesn't read the contents of the `.file_with_backup_register` file. It's reading the output of `find`, which is just the list of all those files.

Comment: `tar` requires arguments specifying the files and directories to put in to the archive. It doesn't look like you're giving it the directory argument.

Comment: ok thx but i still need to while read line but i think i might got a solution. I can type back when i know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the "-T" option with "tar" you can specify the name of a file that contains the names of the files you want to back up.

```
tar -cv -T filelist -f tarball.tar
```

Comment: I want to make a tar of the complete dir and im standing in the dir, whne im running the tar-czvf $(date +%m_%d_%Y). But i think its find/home.... line that dont work. I comented out some lines in my scrip and it creats my temp dir but it dosent cp any files to the dir.

Comment: Tell us what $n is. Can you run "echo $n" and tell us the output. Then run...       find /home -name ".file*with*"

Comment: Hi i solved the problem i had by adding | xargs cat | in my find line and that solved my problem. But the way you suggested seems alot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
$ find $HOME -name file_with_backup_register | xargs cat | xargs -I % cp % /var/backup/temp
```

If you're unsure whether `find` succeeds in locating your register file, just invoke:

```
$ find $HOME -name file_with_backup_register
```

and see if outputs its valid location.

**EDIT** see @Barmar's comment under your question, he's probably right. Nevertheless, above answer could be useful as well, since it simplifies your solution.

Comment: Xargs: invalid option '-J' il get when im trying that line insted, but i can have done something wrong dont really understand how that line works yet.

Comment: @user3176770 - maybe try `-I` instead of `-J`